# what is this 'sequence of arrays' created by numpy's np.stack function in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm reading the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) on np.stack:

> > Join a sequence of arrays along a new axis.
> > output: ndarray

So `np.stack` is going to take, say, 2 numpy array and return what? It will return a new array, which contains a, um, sequence of arrays?

I can't visualize what an array consisting of a sequence of arrays is, so how about I run a little experiment:

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint

arrays = [2.5 * np.random.randn(1,2)+ 3 for _ in range(1,3)] 
arrays = [a.astype(int) for a in arrays]
arrays
```

This gives me:

```
[array([[1, 2]]), array([[2, 3]])]
```

Then,

`np.stack(arrays, axis=0)`

gives

```
array([[[1, 2]],
    
[[2, 3]]])
```

Pretending for a second that the printout is not basically unreadable (10 square brackets, really?), I see what appears to be 2 arrays, in an array, in a ordered sequence. I guess the documentation is correct, but I still have no mental visualization of what this object looks like.

Maybe I should look at the dimensions:

```
np.stack(arrays, axis=0).shape
```

gives

```
(2, 1, 2)
```

So we have two rows, one column, and two layers of this? Isn't that one array?

My questions are:

- What exactly is a 'sequence of arrays' and how does an array possess a notion of order, as does a sequence by definition?
- Why would anyone ever want a 'sequence of arrays' anyway, whatever that is, as opposed to concatenating multiple arrays into one (as the `.shape` implies this really is anyways)?
- Why did they call this function "stack" and how does the colloquial use of this word attempt to be helpful?

Thanks.

**EDIT** too many good answers...having trouble selecting one for the checkmark...

Comment: *How does an array possess a notion of order* - this is a strange question. An array is always ordered, its only constraint (compared to, say, a list) is that it contains elements of the same type. How could it *not* possess a notion of order?

Comment: The natural number line is a set that has a notion of order. You could also think of it as having distance (or measure). Do matrices map one-to-one to the natural number line? If so, then I suppose the set of all matricies would have a notion of order.

Comment: *The natural number line is a set that has a notion of order.* Yes, and the order of a numpy array is the order of its natural-number indices. This is what you get when you e.g. iterate over all elements of the array. The same holds for n-dimensional arrays, where indexing by natural number yields (n-1)-dimensional sub-arrays.

Comment: `stack` does not create a sequence of arrays.  It takes a `sequence of arrays` as input.  Your `arrays` list is just such a sequence.

Answer (score 2):

- *What exactly is a 'sequence of arrays' and how does an array possess a notion of order, as does a sequence by definition?*

  - A sequence is an abstract-data type that, as you intuited, is an ordered collection of items. [In Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html), a sequence can be assumed to implement `__getitem__` and `__len__`, that is, it supports bracketed indexing, e.g. `seq[0]` or `seq[1]`, and has a `len`.  It also implements `__contains__`, `__iter__`, `__reversed__`, `index`, and `count`. Built-in sequence types include `list`, `tuple`, `str`, `bytes`, `range` and `memoryview`. A `numpy.ndarray` is a sequence.
- *Why would anyone ever want a 'sequence of arrays' anyway, whatever that is, as opposed to concatenating multiple arrays into one (as the .shape implies this really is anyways)?*

  - The documentation is letting you know that the function accepts *any* sequence of arrays. A multidimensional array *is* a sequence of arrays, itself, or you can pass a list or tuple of arrays you want to "stack" on top (or up against) each other. The function *returns* a `numpy.ndarray`, which is any numpy array (n-dimensional array).  It is a slightly different operation than `concatenate`. See below.
- *Why did they call this function "stack" and how does the colloquial use of this word attempt to be helpful?*

  - Because it stacks stuff together. According to the [docs for `np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy.stack), it "Join[s] a sequence of arrays along a new axis.", [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) on the other hand: "Join[s] a sequence of arrays along an existing axis."

Looking at the example in [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy.stack) is helpful.

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> b = np.array([2, 3, 4])
>>> np.stack((a, b), axis=0)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])
>>> np.stack((a, b), axis=1)
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4]])
>>>
```

`np.concatenate` does something different:

```
>>> np.concatenate((a,b))
array([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4])
```

It is one of many related stacking, concatenating, appending operations on `np.array`s that come built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy arrays:

```
import numpy
a = np.array([1,2,3])
a.shape gives (3,) -> indicates a 1D array
b = np.array([2, 3, 4])
np.stack((a,b),axis=0) -->Stack the two arrays row-wise which means just put the first arrow on top of the second array
np.stack((a,b),axis=1) -->columns wise stack
```

Now answering your questions in the same order:

1. A sequence of arrays in the above example is a and b , a and b together form a sequence of arrays.
2. The reason this function is useful is - Imagine if you are trying to build a matrix where each row (array) is obtained from some special function specific to that row number , np.stack allows you to stack each array and create a 2D array with ease.
3. In the true sense , stack means placing things over something. In this , you are just adding an array on top of another array.

Hope this helps!

Edit - Based on a comment-

The difference between concatenate and stack (apart from functionality)-
Concat is more like merge

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[5, 6]])

np.stack((a,b),axis=0) ->error
np.concatenate((a,b),axis=0) -->no error
```

Comment: For #2 -- why don't you just concatenate rows? Why stack? What's the difference here?

Comment: Concatenate does not need same shape of arrays whereas stack needs same dimensions. Subtle differences between all the functions.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Python parlance, "sequence" is just a thing that can contain other things, has a sense of "order", and can optionally indexed like `seq[i]`.  Python is duck-typed so anything behaving like a sequence can be called one.  It can be a list or a tuple, for example.  In this case the ordering is definitely important.
2. The sequence can be built up piece-by-piece, as is common in programming.  For example you may download some data using a RESTful API, build an array from each response, and append each one to a list.  After you're done with requesting, you can use the accumulated "sequence of arrays" for your computation later.
3. If you look at the examples on that page it's pretty clear.  You have a list of arrays, let's say, `l = [a, b]` where `a` and `b` are arrays.  What `stack(l)` does is to create a new array with `a` "on top of" `b`, if the shapes are compatible.  Of course there's also `concatenate` but it isn't the same. `stack` creates a new dimension, but `concatenate` *connects* along the axis you specify, as the name suggests.

---

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

# Ten pieces of 3x4 paper, contained in a list, or "sequence"
In [2]: arrays = [np.random.randn(3, 4) for _ in xrange(10)]

# Stack the paper so you get a paperstack with thickness 10 ;)
In [3]: np.stack(arrays, axis=0).shape
Out[3]: (10, 3, 4)

# Join each piece's long side with the next one, so you get a larger piece of paper
In [4]: np.concatenate(arrays, axis=0).shape
Out[4]: (30, 4)
```

From the release note:

> The new function `np.stack` provides a general interface for joining a sequence of arrays along a new axis, complementing `np.concatenate` for joining along an existing axis.

Comment: "sequence" is just a thing that can contain other things. So a sequence is some sort of container?

Comment: Yes, they're containers where the order of elements is important.  Not all containers are sequences (e.g. sets and dictionaries).  There are [7 built-in sequence types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) in Python 2.  In Python 3 things changed somewhat but the idea is mostly the same. `numpy` arrays also behave like sequences.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem starts with `np.random.randn(1,2)` possibly not giving you what you expect.  This is going to give you a `(1,2)` array.

I helps to think of this as a nested list.  The "outer" list has one item, and this item is the "inner" list of two items (in fact this is the exact way it is represented inside the `array()` wrapper).

Now you make a list of two of these arrays.  These brackets are outside the `array` wrapper so it is just a list.  the `np.stack` command, then, moves the brackets inside the wrapper, in a certain way according to the `axis` command. In this case `axis=0`, and the number of elements in the 0 axis becomes the number of items in the outer list.  The other two dimensions move over, and the `shape` becomes `(2,1,2)`

As a list, this would be a list of two items, each item being a list of a single item, this single item being a list of two numbers.

There are many different ways to arrange these arrays, other than `stack`.  The other major one is `np.concatenate`, which will let you join them along an existing axis (`axis=0` will have an output of shape `(2,2)`, while `axis=1` will have shape `(1,4)`)  `stack` is for when you want a new axis to join them along.

Answer (score 0):

`np.stack` is just **concatenate on a new axis**.

Your `arrays` is a list of 2 `(1,2)` shaped arrays.  It is a sequence.

```
In [325]: arrays = [np.array([[1, 2]]), np.array([[2, 3]])]
In [326]: arrays
Out[326]: [array([[1, 2]]), array([[2, 3]])]
In [327]: arrays[0].shape
Out[327]: (1, 2)
In [328]: np.array(arrays)
Out[328]: 
array([[[1, 2]],

       [[2, 3]]])
In [329]: _.shape
Out[329]: (2, 1, 2)
```

That's the same as if we took `np.array` of this list of lists

```
np.array([[[1, 2]],[[2, 3]]])
```

`np.stack` with the default `axis=0` does the same thing:

```
In [332]: np.stack(arrays).shape
Out[332]: (2, 1, 2)
```

It joins the 2 `(1,2)` arrays on a new axis (dimension).  It might be clearer if `arrays` contained 3 arrays, producing a `(3,1,2)` array.

`np.stack` give more flexibility, allowing us to join the arrays on other new axes (I'll flag that with '):

```
In [335]: np.stack(arrays, axis=0).shape
Out[335]: (2', 1, 2)
In [336]: np.stack(arrays, axis=1).shape
Out[336]: (1, 2', 2)
In [337]: np.stack(arrays, axis=2).shape
Out[337]: (1, 2, 2')
```

Regarding the name, it's a spin off of `hstack`, `vstack`, and `column_stack`, which have been part of `numpy` for a long time.  Those are all specialized applications of `np.concatenate`.  And if you look at the code, `np.source(np.stack)`, you'll see that `np.stack` is also just an application of `concatenate`.

The name is not any more exotic than a 'stack of papers'.

---

Your `arrays` list contains 2' (1,2) shaped arrays.  `np.stack` adds a dimension to each (with `reshape`).  For the default axis=0, it reshapes them to (1',1,2).  Then it does a concatenate on the first axis, resulting (2',1,2) shape.